# Linear Mappings With Differentiation

Tags: linear-algebra

[image]

For part (a): To find the Kernel of L, I set f '(x) - f^-1(x) = 0, and try to find all cases where f '(x)=f^-1(x). However, this leads me nowhere. Am I taking the wrong approach?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We have

$$I(f)=f$$
since $I$ is the identity map so you should solve the differential equation
$$f'-f=0$$

Comment: Oh, I see. I had the misconception that the identity map was the inverse of f for some reason. Thank you!